# Why do I need to push into TDI in reverse order on the JTAG?

Tags: arm, jtag

There is 2 JTAG TAP's R5's TAP and CS400's TAP.
the TDI is connected with R5 then CS400 is TDO Such as TDI->R5->CS400->TDO.

For example, IDCODE  code is 1110 and the BYPASS command code is 11111.

If I want to read IDCODE of CS400 and BYPASS R5. then I need to push into TDI: 11111+1110, I thought.

But the reference example said that I need to push into TDI: 0111+11111.

I thought that the JTAG data path mechanism basically works with shift registers like FIFO. I'm confused why I need to push it into TDI in reverse order?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two devices in a chain, in order to send something to the last device, you send the bits for the last device first, and then you must send more bits which you want the first device to ignore, so that the bits that are intended to last device actually are clocked through the first device and arrive at the last device.

So you need to know how many clocks the first device delays the data in order to know when the delayed data comes out and goes to last device.

Comment: I get it. but one thing is not clear for me about TDI in bit reverse bit order.

Comment: @Carter The picture you posted explains it. If you want to end up with 11110 in the last device, you must send out the 0 first and then the 1111, and after that, the 11111 for the first device. Only then the devices have 11111 and 11110 because the 0 has to be the oldest bit which means it must be sent out first. So you need to send the least significant bit of the last device as the first bit.